# Go Iterator reading 1 million rows from Bigquery 10x slower than Java or kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, go, google-bigquery

My intention is to query Biquery and index some fields in Elasticsearch using Go. It will be a one time batch job. Since the team has knowledge in Java we decided to benchmark both languages. I have noticed that Go is working slowly using the "iterator way".

Why this difference in time?.

Do I missing some client or query configuration in Go or that is the expected behavior?.

How can I improve this reading time?

Both Java/kotlin and Go:

- run in the same exact environment.
- Bigquery dataset 200GB
- Same "sql" query, joining two tables and only retrieving 12 ish fields. LIMIT 1 million rows.
- Running example codes from GCP docs for both languages using interactive queries: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/running-queries.

(I have simplified the code)

**Go 1.16.3**

```
...

type Test struct {
    TestNo    *big.Rat              `bigquery:"testNo,nullable"`
    TestId    bigquery.NullString   `bigquery:"testId"`
    TestTime  bigquery.NullDateTime `bigquery:"testTime"`
    FirstName bigquery.NullString   `bigquery:"firstName"`
    LastName  bigquery.NullString   `bigquery:"lastName"`
    Items     []ItemTest            `bigquery:"f0_"`
}

type ItemTest struct {
    ItemType  bigquery.NullString `bigquery:"itemType"`
    ItemNo    bigquery.NullString `bigquery:"itemNo"`
    ProductNo *big.Rat            `bigquery:"productNo,nullable"`
    Qty       *big.Rat            `bigquery:"qty,nullable"`
    Name      bigquery.NullString `bigquery:"name"`
    Price     *big.Rat            `bigquery:"price,nullable"`
}


ctx := context.Background()
client, err := bigquery.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
if err != nil {
    // TODO: Handle error.
}


q := client.Query(myQuery)

it, err := q.Read(ctx)
if err != nil {
    // TODO: Handle error.
}


for {
    start := time.Now().UTC()

    var t Test
    err := it.Next(&t)
    if err == iterator.Done {
        break
    }
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: Handle error.
    }

    end += time.Since(start)

    IndexToES(t)
   
}

fmt.Println(end) //13 minutes.

...
```

takes **13 minutes** to read and map to Go structs.

**Kotlin**

```
...

val start: BigDecimal = Instant.now().toEpochMilli().toBigDecimal().setScale(3)

val bigquery = BigQueryOptions.newBuilder()
            .setCredentials(credentials)
            .setProjectId(PROJECT_ID)
            .build()
            .service

val queryConfig = QueryJobConfiguration.newBuilder(query).build()

val tableResult = bigquery.query(queryConfig)

val test = results.iterateAll()
            .map { myMapper.mapToTest(it) }

val end: BigDecimal = Instant.now().toEpochMilli().toBigDecimal().setScale(3)


logResults(start, end) // 60000ms = 1minute 

fun logResults(start: BigDecimal, end: BigDecimal){
       println("query: " + (pitB - pitA).setScale(0) + "ms") 
}

//iterate through test and indexing at the same time
...
```

Takes **1 minute**...

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Comment: I do not know the answer, since I know very little `go` (even less of itss internals), but it must be again the fantastic way the `JVM` is performing

Answer (score 2):

Neither snippet is complete, so it is unclear if this is apples to apples.  If you're wondering where the time is going in the Go program, consider leveraging [pprof](https://pkg.go.dev/runtime/pprof).

The other thing to point out is that if you're reading millions of rows of query output, you're going to want to take a look at the [BigQuery Storage API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/).  Using this rather than the iterators you're currently testing against can make this faster in both languages.